# Word for "aver the primacy" or "make essential"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a single word (or better set of words) to express e.g.:

- "liberalism *avers the primacy* of the individual", or
- "Johannes *renders* his masculinity *essential*?

Comment: Just FWIW, Liberalism "focusses on" the individual is a common usage in certain such sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, the meaning of [primacy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/primacy) is the state of being the most important or first in estimation, I would say that a term that means to elevate in status would be a good substitute for *aver the primacy*.

[**Exalt**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exalt):  Means something similar to this.  It is to elevate in estimation by praising.

> Liberalism exalts the individual.
>   Johannes exalts his masculinity.

Similarly, [**Aggrandize**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aggrandize); [**Elevate**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elevate); [**Enshrine**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enshrine).

Answer (score 2):

You can consider **[emphasize](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/emphasize)** [AmE] (or emphasise [BrE]) also.

> **1** to give particular importance or attention to something
>
> **3** to make something more noticeable

---

> Liberalism emphasizes the individual.
>
> Johannes emphasises his masculinity.

---

**Special note:** I would like to emphasize David M's answer "exalt" also, especially for the first example.